How to access the TCM on a SpacemiT K1/X60
The SpacemiT K1/X60 has 512KiB of TCM (Tightly Coupled Memory) on its first cluster of 4 cores: https://developer.spacemit.com/documentation?token=Alhewa0fai7lvbk9sajcumNqn4f
The TCM is mapped to 0xD800000 in the physical address space: https://developer.spacemit.com/documentation?token=LzJyw97BCipK1dkUygrcbT0NnMg
I don't really see anything in the documentation about accessing this memory.
I see that some ARM CPUs expose a TCM through asm/tcm.h with tcm_alloc()/tcm_free() and some other utilities: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/include/asm/tcm.h
Looking at SpacemiTs linux kernel source, I see the TCM in the device tree: https://github.com/BPI-SINOVOIP/pi-linux/blob/linux-6.6.36-k1/arch/riscv/boot/dts/spacemit/k1-x.dtsi#L2275-L2299 but I don't see an equivalent to arm's tcm.h
The TCM infrastructure on ARM seems to be somewhat more elaborate than just a flat mapping to physical memory: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/tcm.c . Would it make sense to just implement something like a more simple tcm.c/h in the kernel and expose it that way?
EDIT: Found the driver, also the lines referencing the DT: https://github.com/BPI-SINOVOIP/pi-linux/blob/linux-6.6.36-k1/drivers/misc/tcm.c#L586-L590 . Haven't figured out how to use it yet.
EDIT2:
Got something working with
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define IOC_MAGIC       'c'
#define TCM_MEM_SHOW        _IOR(IOC_MAGIC, 2, int)
#define TCM_VA_TO_PA        _IOR(IOC_MAGIC, 4, int)
#define TCM_REQUEST_MEM     _IOR(IOC_MAGIC, 5, int)
#define TCM_RELEASE_MEM     _IOR(IOC_MAGIC, 6, int)

int main()
{
    int fd = open("/dev/tcm", O_RDWR);
    if (-1 == fd)
    {
        printf("Failed to open tcm\n");
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned long arg = 0;
    ioctl(fd, TCM_MEM_SHOW, arg);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

using this code I was able to get the following in the kernel messages:
[2543369.524828] mem block id(0):
[2543369.524852] mm_show start
[2543369.524859] mem free node[0]: ffffffd904559240 paddr: d8000000 size:0x20000
[2543369.524867] mm_show end
[2543369.524870] mem block id(1):
[2543369.524874] mm_show start
[2543369.524878] mem free node[0]: ffffffd904559280 paddr: d8020000 size:0x20000
[2543369.524884] mm_show end
[2543369.524889] mem block id(2):
[2543369.524893] mm_show start
[2543369.524897] mem free node[0]: ffffffd9045592c0 paddr: d8040000 size:0x20000
[2543369.524903] mm_show end
[2543369.524907] mem block id(3):
[2543369.524910] mm_show start
[2543369.524914] mem free node[0]: ffffffd904559300 paddr: d8060000 size:0x20000
[2543369.524920] mm_show end

I'm assuming the other ioctls will work as well. it does require root privileges by default.
